# Countable Discrete Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, proof-explanation

I’d like to show that a countable discrete space X is locally Euclidean of dimension 0. I know that the way to do this is by showing that each point in X has a neighborhood homemorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{0}$. The problem is that I’m not quite sure what $\mathbb{R}^{0}$ means. I was able to show that every countable discrete space has a countable basis and is trivially Hausdorff. Hence showing that it is locally Euclidean of dimension 0 means that it is a 0 dimensional manifold.

Comment: $\mathbb R^{0}$ is  nothing  but a set with a single point, say $\{0\}$ (which has only one tolopology).

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy, is it possible to write it in terms of set notation?

Comment: It is just a singleton $\{0\}$, a set consisting of $0$ as its only element.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb R^n$ is the standard model of a real vector space of dimension $n$. Thus $\mathbb R^0$ is a $0$-dimensional real vector space, thus it only contains a single element.